Looking for cable management items
I have tried various stick on cable management things such as the image.  They have proved useless.  The adhesive does not last long. The reason is that the surface area of the adhesive itself is minimal.
I am looking for a strip to

Anchor maybe 6 cables to my desk.
They should be free to slide, but not fall out through the holes.
Cables will be USB, speaker and ethernet.
Strong adhesive preferred.  Screws as a last resort.



Consider to research the various 3D printer repositories, such as Cults3D, Thingiverse, Prusa Printables with appropriate search terms such as cable organizer. Each of the above links return that search term.
There will be duplications, but also a multitude of selections that one can 3D print. Not everybody has a 3D printer, but there's an app for that. Not really, but there is a reddit for requesting prints to be created on commission.
If you can't find what you want in the above repositories, there are others you may find with an appropriate search.
Additionally, you may find something close to what you seek and another reddit for requesting modifications may result in another commission to modify, create and/or print your objective.
Regarding the adhesive aspect, with off-the-shelf items and especially anything 3D printed, the quality of double stick tapes can vary substantially. My experience with 3M foam tapes has been quite good with the high strength (pricey) stuff, holding well in Florida heat and sun.
The surface to which the item is applied is also important. Clean paint, plastic, steel, even smooth wood will bond well, but irregular surfaces that are difficult to clean will result in disappointment.
